# Find a number's inverse using multiplication only

Tags: proof-writing, axioms

Some taking-a-shower thinking:

Given $x$, find $1/x$ using multiplication only.

I understand these axioms

$$
n \times inv(n) = 1
$$
$$
n \div d = n \times inv(d)
$$

But I couldn't think of a way to derive $1/x$ from $x$ using only multiplication.

I'm a *complete* math noob but if it's not possible, I'm interested in a proof that demonstrates it as fact

Comment: this is *not* an assignment – other than it being some I assigned myself to think about. I have 0% certainty that a "solution" to my question exists.

Comment: What do you mean by "find 1/x"? If x is 4, then 1/x is 1/4.  No multiplication needed.  Perhaps you could clarify? Cheers!

Comment: @MatthewConroy I just want to know if it's possible to derive `1/x` from `x` using multiplication. `1/x` is division. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean by "derive"? If x=4, then 1/x is 1/4. What is there to "derive"?

Comment: @MatthewConroy I mean if `x = 5`, and `inv(x) = 0.2`, "find" or "derive" `0.2` from `5` using only multiplication – I'm sorry my math terminology probably sucks.

Comment: Its a great question.  Simple answer, there is none.  At least not in general.  you simply have to guess.  What is it such that $x * a = 1$?  What ever it is that is $1/x$.  On the other hand you can make educated guesses.  I know 2x4 =8 and I know $1/4 = .25$  So 1/8 must the a so ax8 = 1 so ax2x4 = 1 so ax2 = .25.  And I know 1/2 = .5 so $ax2x.6 = .25x.5 = .125.$  and....

Comment: ... there are other number systems then just the reals.  Z_7 = the numbers 1,...7 and then you return to 1 all over again (circular remainders).  So 5+3 = 2 (because you count to 7 and go back to 1).  The a = 1/3 means 3a = 1 = go back to 1 = 1 + 7k so 3a - 7k = 1.  If $k=2$ and $a = 5$ we get 15-14 = 1.  So 3x5 = 5 + 5 + 5.  5+5 = 3.  And 3 + 5 = 1.  So 1/3 = 5.  And 3x5 = 1.

Comment: In decimals.  We know $1/5$ is that so that $1/5*5 = 1$  So that means $1/5*10 = 1/5*(5*2) = (1/5*5)*2 = 1*2 = 2$.  And $1/5 = 1/5* (10*1/10) = (1/5*10)*1/10 = 2*1/10$.  And we just invent to notation $.abcd = abcd/10^k$ so as $1/5 = 2*1/10$ we know $1/5 = .2$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the numbers you are dealing with are strictly in the field $\mathbb{R}$, of real numbers with standard multiplication, $*$. A field is an algebraic structure where multiplicative inverses exist and these inverses are unique (I can provide a proof if you wish). The inverse of an element $n$ is denoted $n^{-1}$ and satisfies $n * n^{-1} = 1$. Note that $n^{-1}$ really depends on the operation which you are taking inverse of (We stick with multiplication for your sake). There is no way to explicitly compute your inverse using multiplication but the above just shows that it exists and is unique.

As requested, here is a proof for uniqueness:

Assume $m, m'$ are multiplicative inverses for $n$. Then $n*m = 1 = n*m'$. Therefore, $m = 1*m = (n*m')*m = (m'*n)*m = m'*(n*m) = m'*1 = m'$.

Comment: O___O ok very, very cool. Gollum forgot about negative exponents. The proof does interest me if you're willing to provide it. Now I suppose I have to read up on the behavior of negative exponents.

Comment: There isn't much to read on negative exponents.

Comment: Ah I see, $n^{-1}$ is exactly equal to $1/n^{1}$.. hmm

Comment: Negative inverses are just notation that $n^{-1}$ is number $a$ so that $a*n =1$.  Another notation is $\frac 1n$.  The only real thing to not is that the inverse of $n^k$ turns out to be the same thing as $inv(n)^k$ (that's a straight forward proof). In other word $\frac 1{n^k} = (n^k)^{-1}$ is the same thing as $(\frac 1n)^k = (n^{-1})^k$.  So it is fair and legal to say $n^{-k}$ to mean either the inverse of $n^k$ or $inv(n)^k$.

Answer (score 1):

While there's no way to get an *exact* answer using just multiplication, it's worth noting that it's possible to generate *approximate* answers; in fact, this is how most CPUs have traditionally done division, by using a version of *Newton's method* for root-finding.  Starting with a very rough approximation $x_0$ to $\frac1n$ (usually found in practice by table lookup), we can compute much better ones by setting $x_1=x_0\times(2-nx_0)$, $x_2=x_1\times(2-nx_1)$, etc; this is the same as saying that $x_{i+1} = x_i+x_i\times (1-nx_i)$ — note that if $x_i$ is close to $\frac1n$, then $1-nx_i$ will be very close to zero, so $x_{i+1}$ will be pretty close to $x_i$ and thus also pretty close to $\frac1n$.  In fact, it'll be closer; if the relative error in $x_i$, that is $1-nx_i$, is $\varepsilon$, then the relative error in $x_{i+1}$ will be $1-n\times x_{i+1}$ $=1-n\times(x_i\times(2-nx_i))$ $=1-2nx_i+n^2x_i^2$ $=(1-nx_i)^2$ $=\varepsilon^2$. In other words, every iteration doubles the number of correct digits in the approximation.

You can try this yourself: suppose we want to compute $\frac17$. Well, $7$ is kind of close to $10$, so we'll start with $x_0=.1$.  Now, we iterate:
$$x_1=x_0(2-7x_0)=.1(2-.7)=.1\times1.3=.13$$
$$x_2 = x_1(2-7x_1)=.13(2-.91)=.13\times1.09=.1417$$
$$x_3 = x_2(2-7x_2)=.1417(2-.9919)=.1417\times1.0091=.14298947$$
And this is only about $.0001$ away from the actual value $.\overline{142857}$

Answer (score 0):

Strictly base 10 decimals.  To get $\frac 1{2^k5^m}$.  e.g. to get $\frac 1{16}$ or $\frac 1{625}$ or $\frac 1{400}$.

$\frac 1{2^k5^m} * 2^k5^m = 1$ so

$\frac 1{2^k5^m} * 10^{\max(m,k)} =$

$\frac 1{2^k5^m} *(2^{\max(m,k)}5^{\max(m,k)}=$

$\frac 1{2^k5^m}*2^k5^m*2^{\max(m,k)-k}5^{\max(m,k)-m}=$

$1*2^{\max(m,k)-k}5^{\max(m,k)-m}=2^{\max(m,k)-k}5^{\max(m,k)-m}$

So

$\frac 1{2^k5^m} = $

$\frac 1{2^k5^m}*10^{\max(m,k)}*\frac 1{10^{\max(m,k)}}=$

$2^{\max(m,k)-k}5^{\max(m,k)-m}\frac 1{10^{\max(m,k)}}=$

$.2^{\max(m,k)-k}5^{\max(m,k)-m}$

Ex $\frac 1{16} = $

$\frac 1{16}*10000*\frac 1{10000}$

$\frac 1{16}*2^4*5^4*\frac 1{10000}=$

$\frac 1{16}*16*625 *\frac 1{10000}=$

$625 *\frac 1{10000}=.0625$.